# Stereo, echo sound effects in MPlayer after upgrade to Big Sur

Tags: audio, macports, mplayer

After upgrading to macOS BigSur (v11) I notice strange effects in music playback with `MPlayer`. It sounds as if there is a new equaliser enabled. The music sounds to be played back in stereo and sometimes I hear echo effects and maybe a tiny delay. Imagine a playback speed of 0.9. I don't welcome these effects, especially when I listen to Chopin and other classical recordings.

Would you please help me to diagnose the issue and try to reinstate the original sound playback without these new effects? I use `MPlayer 1.3.0-12.0.0` from MacPorts v2.6.4 @ macOS Big Sur 11.1.

Please find below the output of MPlayer during playback of an audio file in Flac format:

```
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 1033.5 kbit/73.23% (ratio: 129183->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffflac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg FLAC audio)

AO: [coreaudio] Unable to initialize Output Unit component: [D���]
AO: [openal] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
```

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly same problem (but installed from Homebrew), solved by upgrading to mplayer 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Reimar Döffinger on MPlayer-users mailing list suggests to check, whether `coreaudio` fails before `OpenAL` is used. To do that launch MPlayer in verbose mode on an MP3 file:

```
mplayer -msglevel all=6 track01.mp3
```

In my case it fails with the following error:

```
AO: [coreaudio] Unable to initialize Output Unit component: [D���].
```

The resolution is to install the [Simple DirectMedia Layer (SDL)](https://www.libsdl.org/) MacPorts variant of the MPlayer:

```
sudo port install mplayer +sdl
```

To view all variants of a given port:

```
sudo port variants mplayer
```

To view the installed version of a given port (and its variants):

```
sudo port installed | grep mplayer
```